# How to implement custom NavigationController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, user-profile

I have an application which uses a NavigationController and a TabBarController to navigate easily through different views. For some views, I have a title and some buttons (sometimes only on the right, sometimes on the right and on the left). For some views, however, for example when watching someone's profile, I don't want to set a title. I want to show the profile picture and add the name of the user underneath the picture.

My question is pretty simple: should I use a NavigationController for this, as I want the profile picture to go "over" the NavigationController, making it only 16 pixels from the status bar and NOT from the NavigationController. Would that be possible while still having left and right buttons (to edit the profile if it's your own, for example, or for a "more options" button).

I have been thinking about using an entirely different approach where I don't use a NavigationController but instead use a label to show the title if necessary and add a view on the left and on the right where I could add the buttons if necessary.

As this is the first time I'm doing something like this, I would love to hear your opinions about how to achieve this result and what the best practice is. Something tells me it would be better to use a NavigationController as this is what it's meant to do, but how can I then implement the optional title and go over it if needed? I already know how to remove the bottom hairline and how to set the background color accordingly, so that won't be the biggest issue. I am merely concerned about how to show the image over the NavigationController.

Thanks guys!

Comment: How do you want to "segue" between views? Using either (a) Storyboard segues or (b) push/pop transitions, you'll gain a lot with a navigation controller. It's possible to extend a `UIView` to mimic the "back" or "pop" transition, but then you'll need a container view. And of course, if you're simply presenting your view controllers, you won't need a navigation controller.

Comment: I don’t use Storyboards and do everything in code, so currently I push them indeed. Would be a pity to lose that and a lot of added work to make transitions, show the right buttons etc. Can I, however, achieve what I want with a NagigationController?

Comment: Can't really say. I've subclassed a `UINavigationController` in my latest project but haven't tried to "replace" the title like you want. I've set it to a null string though. I'm sure you can create your own "titleLabel" (there is no such public property in a nav bar) but I'm not sure about using auto layout for placement. Before I subclassed things, I actually went the other route - made my own nav bar using plain `UIViews` and transitioning pretty close to what you get with push/pop. But yeah, "pretty close" is about what you'll get.

Comment: Last comments. I needed  toolbox with up to 4 table views to navigate through - *but* - as a child view controller. Since it's a subclass of `UIViewController`, I found that a `UINavigationController` works just fine. It has it's own view, and I just needed to add the other controllers for it. I added a delegate protocol, floated the methods up to the actual parent as needed, and that was it! I just checked, and you *can* treat the nav controller's view like any other, turning off the auto resizing mask. I'd start with that and see if you can just add a subview and constraints. Good luck.

Comment: I’ll look into it. I also had no idea I could treat it like that. Might give me the flexibility I need. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Guess I lied, one more thought. My needs were strict - child view controller. If you wish for a "full screen" navigation controller without a storyboard, remember to make it the window's root view controller.

Comment: I am currently experimenting with the zPosition of the layer. By changing this to -1, the image can be set over the navigationController by using a negative topAnchor for the imageView. Not sure if this is best practice though and a “bug” appears when going to a child from the parent where the navigationBar is a lightGray color instead of plain white, but it changes to white again when the view is loaded (I think).

Comment: Ok. I have a working demo. I'm only using colored UIViews, but it has everything you need. The toughest thing was getting the title view height correct including rotation, as I had to account for the status bar and the fact that the bottom of the nav controller is the screen bottom. If this works for you I'llpost the relevent code as an answer. The repo is here: https://github.com/justdfd/UINavigationController

Comment: Just took a look at your example. It does indeed do what I need it to do - if I make the views larger - for example a heightAnchor with a constant of 200 on blueView, it still does exactly what I need it to do - start in the navigationController and continue inside the "content". I will take a closer look on how you achieved this after dinner - but pretty sure this will be the hack (if I can call it that?) I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to create a custom "titleLabel" is to subclass both `UIView` and `UINavigationController`. A demo of doing this is [here](https://github.com/justdfd/UINavigationController).

The main pieces are with the navigation controller. Basically, you want to leave the `title` property empty (a null string or just don't set it) and, since `UINavigationController` is just a subclass of `UIViewController` working as a container view with push/pop capabilities, work with your subclass in that manner. In my demo, my subclassed nav controller class is called `NavigationController`.

In my opinion, the main advantage you get from subclassing `UINavigationController` *is* using it's push/pop capabilities... while you can use segues they require a storyboard, and while you can use a `UIView` animation, it just doesn't feel as "smooth" to me.

**(1) If you aren't working with a Storyboard, remember to set this subclass as your root view controller in `AppDelegate`:**

```
var navController: NavigationController?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    navController = NavigationController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.window!.rootViewController = navController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

**(2) While there re other ways to do this, my preference is to instantiate the view controllers in my subclass, exposing methods to push/pop as needed:**

```
class NavigationController:UINavigationController {

    let redVC = RedViewController()
    let greenVC = GreenViewController()
    let titleView = TitleView()
    var titleViewHeightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint!

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        pushViewController(redVC, animated: false)  // display the first VC
    }
    func popGreenVC() {
        popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    func pushGreenVC() {
        pushViewController(greenVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**(3) In the other VCs, set your left/right buttons as needed and push/pop as needed. I like a custom "arrow" using UTF-8 characters:**

```
class RedViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        let showGreenVC = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Green \u{25B6}", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(pushGreenVC))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = showGreenVC
    }
    @objc func pushGreenVC() {
        let navController = self.navigationController as! NavigationController
        navController.pushGreenVC()
    }
}

class GreenViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        let showRedVC = UIBarButtonItem(title: "\u{25C0} Red", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(popGreenVC))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = showRedVC
    }
    @objc func popGreenVC() {
        let navController = self.navigationController as! NavigationController
        navController.popGreenVC()
    }
}
```

Note that I am force-casting the view's `naviagtionController?` property as my subclassed type. The casting is needed to gain access to the custom methods in it.

**(4) Next up, include your custom "titleView". For demo purposes I created a 50/50 yellow/blue one. Note that it uses auto layout anchors:**

```
class TitleView: UIView {
    let yellowView = UIView()
    let blueView = UIView()
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        yellowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        yellowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        blueView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.addSubview(yellowView)
        self.addSubview(blueView)

        yellowView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        yellowView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        yellowView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        yellowView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        blueView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yellowView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        blueView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        blueView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

(5) In the nav controller's init, add code to add your title view. Note that I'm using auto layout with **two** things. First, I'm setting the width to be 1/3 of the status bar width. You can experiment - with an image you may be better off setting a constant width. Second, note the usage of a "named" constraint called `titleViewHeightConstraint`. I'll explain that in the next step.

```
titleViewHeightConstraint = titleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
titleViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
titleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
titleView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
titleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true
```

**(5) Make the height of your title label dynamic:**

Remember, a `UINavigationController` is really a container view controller is all aspects. It's "root" view is full screen, so if you anchor your title label to the bottom, you get a label that is vertically sized from top to bottom. Worse, sometimes a status bar is there, particularly if it's in portrait. But other times (the default landscape) it isn't. For the reason I use the `safeAreaLayoutGuide` of *both* the navigation controller (which detects is there is a status bar present) *and* the view controllers within it (which detects the height of the nav bar PLUS the status bar).

**(5a) Add this method to your navigation controller:**

```
func changeTitleViewHeight(to:CGFloat) {
    titleViewHeightConstraint.constant = to - view.safeAreaInsets.top
}
```

**(5b) And add this override to all the view controllers inside the subclassed nav controller:**

```
override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
    let navController = self.navigationController as! NavigationController
    navController.changeTitleViewHeight(to: view.safeAreaInsets.top)
}
```